# How to use pointer to typedef struct in Cython Extension Type

Tags: python, cython

Say I have the following `typedef struct` in my header file `example.h`:

```
typedef struct A A;
```

I am tring to make a Cython Extension Type with a pointer to `A` as a class variable in `test.pyx`, and then I call an initialization function `f` on a reference to `A`:

```
cdef class Test:
    cdef A* a

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.a = a
        f(&a)
    ...
```

When I compile `test.pyx, I end up with the following compilation errors:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef class Test:
    cdef A* a

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.a = a
                                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx: undeclared name not builtin: a

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

cdef class Test:
    cdef A* a

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.a = a
                                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx: Cannot convert Python object to 'A *'
```

Apparently it is not recognizing the object `a`, and it is interpreting it as a python object. How can I fix this?

Comment: If that is all the cython definitions you have, I think you should read cython documentation and study the examples a little bit.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have to declare it before you use it. For example you have this in your c code `example.h` :

```
typedef struct struct_name{
    int a;
    float b;
}struct_alias;
```

Then your `.pyx` file should look like:

```
cdef extern from "example.h":
    ctypedef struct struct_alias:
        int a
        int b

cdef class Test:
    cdef A* a

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.a = a
        f(&a)
    ...
```